# UWP C# Camera - Get/display a stream or a preview

Tags: c#, camera, uwp, windows-phone

I would like to get the stream of the camera, in order to preview it and do some actions on it (such as taking pictures), but also, in order to integrate my own design, which isn't possible with the `MediaCapture` logic...

Any idea?

Thank in advance!

Comment: What is not possible? you can use `MediaCapture` to get the camera stream and use [`CaptureElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CaptureElement) to display it.

Comment: How? Because I've been searching for so long and I can't make it work.. it open me a new "activity" or the natif design :/

Comment: Did you get permission?

Comment: [Camera](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera): Take a look at this link. It will contain all the things you need.

Comment: "in order to integrate my own design," Could you please details what your design? In that case we may find more exact tutorial for you.

Comment: I mean like, I have the camera as a background like, a control `<Camera/>` in my main `<AbsoluteLayout/>`. Then, once I placed it, I would like to put some others control around which are connected to the camera, but also to some other possibilities (e.g. Snapchat mainscreen camera). Please take a look at this -> https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/284757. It's more general but can maybe help you to understand my goals